# lsnrctl start rane when i fireing this command this error comeing

Tags: oracle, database-administration

```
[oracle@myserver ~]$ lsnrctl start rane

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 27-SEP-2016 23:04:58

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /oraeng/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
System parameter file is /home/oracle/listener.ora
Log messages written to /oraeng/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/log/diag/tnslsnr/myserver/rane/alert/log.xml
TNS-01150: The address of the specified listener name is incorrect

Listener failed to start. See the error message(s) above...
```

This is my listener configuration:

```
LISTENER =
 (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =192.168.246.128)(PORT =152101 ))
   )
  )
 )
 SID_LIST_LISTENER=
  (SID_LIST=
   (SID_DESC= (SID_NAME = raneesh)
   (ORACLE_HOME =/oraeng/app/oracle/product/11.2.0 )
  )
 )
```

Comment: Perhaps the address specified in your `listener.ora` is incorrect?

Comment: Why are you trying to start a listener named RANE ?  Why not just go with the default listener name of LISTENER?  No one can tell you exactly what is wrong since you did not share the contents of listener.ora.

Comment: [oracle@oracle ~]$ lsnrctl start LISTENER

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 02-OCT-2016 13:12:21

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /oraeng/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
System parameter file is /home/oracle/listener.ora
Log messages written to /oraeng/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/log/diag/tnslsnr/oracle/listener/alert/log.xml
TNS-01150: The address of the specified listener name is incorrect

Listener failed to start. See the error message(s) above...

Comment: same errorLISTENER =
        (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
        (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =192.168.246.128)(PORT =152101 ))
                )
        )
    )
        SID_LIST_LISTENER=
        (SID_LIST=
        (SID_DESC=
                (SID_NAME = raneesh)
        (ORACLE_HOME =/oraeng/app/oracle/product/11.2.0 )
)
)
 this my listener

Answer (score 1):

The port number you have specified is not valid. The usual port number for a listener is 1521, but if you want to use a different value it still has to be in the valid range, with a maximum of 65535, and avoiding the well-known ports up to 1024. The number you have tried to use, 152101, is well outisde the allowed range.

[Read more about port numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)).